# Will c-lightning's `withdraw destination all` take anything from the channel funds?

Tags: core-lightning, sweep

Will c-lightning's `withdraw destination all` take anything from the channel funds?

Does the string `all` that can be  used  to specify  withdrawal of all available funds refer only to onchain funds with `"status": "confirmed"` in `listfunds`'s result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `withdraw` command makes an *onchain* transaction to send a given amount of *onchain* funds to the specified `destination`. It will not close any channel beforehand to withdraw funds locked there.

Whether or not it will sweep unconfirmed UTxOs as well is specified to the command via the `minconf` optional parameter, which can be set to `0`. See the [manpage](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/lightning-withdraw.7.html) for more details on the usage of the command.

So, yes, by default it refers only to UTxOs with the `status` field set to `confirmed` in `listfunds`. Note however that `withdraw <addr> all` will not sweep the reserved UTxOs (those with a `reserved_to_block` block field superior to the current block height in `listfunds`'s result).